# phpunit less verbose output

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am running phpunit (on a laravel app) and it outputs all failing cases with their expectations. Can I run it in such a way that it only shows a string of . and F and not the rest? Or can I run it in 'tap' format with only 'ok' and 'not ok'?

I can't find any option for it.

Answer (score 1):

`phpunit` itself doesn't support this. But here is a perl one-liner that will print out `.` for tests that pass and and `E` for failures:

```
phpunit --tap | perl -ne '$|=1;print "." if (/^ok/); print "E" if (/^not ok/)'
```

The `$|=1` is perl magic for turning off output buffering.

Comment: I figured if I want to not see the output I can always cut it off with ```phpunit | head -8```.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what you asked.